# Extracting output only from the current directory

Tags: unix, find, extract

How can I extract from the output of find . -name "*.c" -print only filenames in the current directory?

Why does it always include the subdirectories?

Need help with getting aorund that.

Answer (score 2):

If you need files (or folders) from the current directory that end with `.c`, simply do:

```
ls *.c
```

If you need `find` to only look at your current directory, use:

```
find . -name "*.c" -maxdepth 1
```